# Static Operation like java in c#

Tags: c#, java, static

In java you can add static operation block in any class and it will be called when the application start:

```
class test{
   static{
    //do some operation when the application starts.
   }
}
```

What is the equivalent in c#?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent in C# is the static constructor:

```
class Test
{ 
   static Test()
   { 
    //do some operation before accessing to any member of the class
   } 
}
```

The static constructor is guaranteed to be executed before any class member is accessed. It's not guaranteed to be called at application start though.

Comment: In fact, it’s guaranteed *not* to be called at application startup, only when the class is first accessed. But the same holds for Java, as far as I know.

Answer (score 3):

C# has the [static constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
class Test {
    static Test() {
        // …
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's called a static constructor:

```
class test
{
    static test()
    {
        //do some operation when the application starts.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use static constructor

```
class test
{
    static test()
    {
        // do some job
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I recall properly it's not easy, you have to resort to static contructors.
Try to take a look here [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/csref/html/vclrfStaticConstructors.asp)